# VIM Command-T plugin: how to build the cache index in silent mode at startup?

Tags: vim, plugins

I am using VIM with Command-T plugin with is an awesome tool, but when it is started for the first time it takes a while (~20-30 seconds) to build a cache index, which is a bit annoying. Is there any way to call Command-T build cache function in silent mode at VIM startup?

Comment: I hope there is a way to avoid that.

Comment: You could always put a plugin in `~/.vim/after/plugin` that calls `:CommandTFlush`. But I'm not sure how to make that call non-blocking

Answer (score 1):

You can run external commands asynchronously, but the Vimscript runtime itself is single-threaded; the only way to run Vimscript in parallel would be launching another Vim instance, and having it write the results into a file which is then read by the original Vim instance.

Command-T is based on Ruby; maybe there's a way to run that asynchronously. I would recommend you bring this up with the plugin's author.

Comment: One thing: python threading (not on ARM for some reason) and multiprocessing (everywhere I tested) modules are working in vim. It is likely that ruby equivalent will also work.

Comment: But in the autoflushing pull request author [said](https://github.com/wincent/Command-T/pull/13#issuecomment-8392130) “I'm also wary of anything that is not single-threaded, as Vim itself is a single-threaded application and I worry about the stability of changing that model from inside a plug-in.”

Answer (score 0):

There are two pull requests that make the issue not so severe:
[autoflushing index on disk changes](https://github.com/wincent/Command-T/pull/13) and [caching index to disk](https://github.com/wincent/Command-T/pull/36).